Stpm33 Power meter insulation
I m developing a board based on stpm33 Power meter based on a demoboard evalstpm33. Stpm33 requires both current an voltage to evaluate Power. For voltage It use 220 vac scaled to a 0.3V max using resistor partition. I would likes to know if can I use a 1:1 transformer tò insulate my board from 220vac without issues (ex., phase shift). As said voltage level are low and I think stpm33 shows High Z on the input stage so also current are low. Can you also indicate a good transformer for these low signals at 50 Hz frequency?

So you think It can be done with audio transformer. For phase shift I thought that with such low voltage +/-0.3V and low current (uA), phase shift due to magnetization was negligible. What you think?
